# Error in Exposed Filter with AJAX in Drupal View

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I'm receiving an error when i try to filter a Drupal view using a regular exposed filter with AJAX(autosubmit).

```
An error occured while attempting to process /views/ajax: 
Object [object Window] has no method 'indexOf'
```

This is what i've done:

- Clear all the cache, run cron and update.php
- Views, ctools and drupal core were out-of-date, so i update them and run update.php
- Check that the view had Ajax enabled.
- Test if using Better Exposed Filters worked, din't work.
- Install JQuery Update module and enable it, din't work either.
- Create another exposed filters(by date, type, title) same error.

**Something important to mention is that the filters works in the View Preview.**

The view is very simple, the only thing it does is show a list of events (event content type) and i want to filter the content by the restaurant (wich is a select list of the content type) and that error is been shown.

This is the spects:

- Drupal Core: 7.19
- Views Module: 7.x-3.5
- PHP Version: 5.3.18
- Apache2.2.22
- MySQL 5.1.66
- Using Acquia Dev Desktop stack on Windows.

Thanks in advance

This is the result code when i export the view:

[File Code, Click Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6sexqb896vm87p/Exported_View.php)

Comment: Could you export your view and paste the code please?

Comment: Hi DnBase, i put the code here https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6sexqb896vm87p/Exported_View.php , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable clean URLS. This worked with me.